# Make an image span the entire width of the Browser using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a large image which I want to display using the entire width of the browser.

My code is:

```
<html><body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <h3> Welcome! </h3>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="main_image">
                <img src="..."/>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="main_content">....</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body></html>
```

Bootstrap will automatically create margins/padding to make the image fit in the center of the page.

Is there a way to always allow the main image to fit the entire width of the browser, but keep the padding/margins for everything else on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to assign the image as a background-image.

Here's a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/qoaqjgpz) with only the most important stuff from http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-width-pics/.

The .html:

```
<div class="image-bg-fixed-height">
</div>
```

The .css:

```
.image-bg-fixed-height {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/1920/500/') no-repeat center center scroll;
    height: 450px;
}

.img-center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Let me know if this is what you were searching for.